# Xampp: Mysql installed but unable to see Admin UI

Tags: mysql, xampp

I'm using xampp and have installed it successfully on my machine. When I start the MySql service from xampp, it is started successfully (Green) and the console logs also says that process is successfully started.

But when I go and click on the 'Admin' button in xampp for MySql service, the Admin UI is NOT displayed on the browser. It says

```
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.19
```

The url is `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/`
I also tried `http://localhost:3306/phpmyadmin/` since mysql service is started on 3306 but that also didn't helped.

Any suggestions on whats going wrong here?
i'm using Windows 7 64 bit machine.

Comment: does localhost load correctly? can you follow the phpmyadmin link on there?

Comment: yes, the localhost loads correctly, problem occurs only when trying to load mysql admin

Comment: browse to your web root folder via windows explorer. do you see the phpmyadmin folder?

Comment: Thanks, but I just uninstalled and re-installed it and it is now working fine. I assume something might be missed when I installed it initially. @doveyg, thx for the help.